# STL like iterator over a collection of hash maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I'm looking for a way to create a forward iterator which allows to iterate over a collection of hash maps.

An exemplary class which holds several maps looks like follows. (I'm using boost for `unordered_map` and `shared_ptr`, but C++11 would provide those classes as well).
In my particular application I'm using this construct to represent sparse hierarchical 2D grid locations; i.e. `KeyT` is a 2D location, `ValueT` is an integral counter and the different levels represent different resolutions  of the grid.

```
template <typename KeyT, typename ValueT>
class MapCollection
{
public:
  // type-definitions for the map and a shared pointer to the map
  typedef boost::unordered_map<KeyT, ValueT> Map;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Map> MapPtr;

  // Constructor for class
  MapCollection (int num_levels)
  {
    levels_.reserve (num_levels);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_levels; ++i)
      levels_.push_back (MapPtr (new Map()));
  }

  // adds a key-value pair to the map on the given level
  void addValue (const KeyT &key, const ValueT &value)
  {
    int level = getLevelForKey (key);
    (*levels_[level])[key] = value;
  }

  // TODO define const_iterator for this class
  // TODO define member function begin(), returning levels_.front()->begin()
  // TODO define member function end(), returning levels_.back()->end()

private:
  // return the hierarchy level for the given key
  int getLevelForKey (const KeyT &key) { return /* ... */ };

  // collection of maps
  std::vector<MapPtr> levels_;
};
```

Within an application I would now like to be able to iterate over all entries of all maps, similarly to what is possible if one just iterates over a single map, i.e.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num_levels = 5;
  MapCollection maps (num_levels);

  // fill maps
  maps.addValue ( /* ... */ )

  // iterator over all entries
  MapCollection::const_iterator iter = maps.begin();
  for (; iter != maps.end(); ++iter)
  {
    std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << " | Value: " << iter->second << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Obviously it would be possible to iterator over the different levels and for each level over it's map, but I would like to hide the creation of different levels for the user.

What is the correct way to define an `(const_)iterator` for the class `MapCollection`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using `auto` eventually?

Comment: I'm unclear what is wrong with your proposed solution of iterating over each level, then iterating over each element in the map at that level.  You said "I would like to hide the creation of different levels" but I am not sure what that means in the context of an iterator.

Comment: Look up [`boost::join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html).

Comment: @MobyDisk I would like to use instances of `MapCollection` in functions with arguments `InputIt first, InputIt last`. There no notion of a level exists.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the hint. `boost::join` allows to combine two ranges. Thus, for n levels I would need joint (n-1) ranges. I went with netvitpc answer since it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **boost iterator facade**, that will help you with the task of implementing custom iterators. The idea would be:

1-maintain a reference to the vector containing the maps (`levels_`).
2-a iterator indicating what element of the previous vector the custom iterator is iterating (of type `std::vector<MapPtr>::iterator` or `std::vector<MapPtr>::const_iterator`) or a index with the same info (to retrieve the end of `level_[index]`).
3-a iterator with current element of the iteration of the previous iterator (*the actual element of the iteration*).

Some sample code:

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

namespace impl
{
    template <class Value>
    class iterator
      : public boost::iterator_facade<
            config_iterator<Value>
          , Value
          , boost::forward_traversal_tag
        >
    {
     public:
        config_iterator() {...}
        explicit config_iterator(parameters) { /*your specific contructor*/ }

     private:
        template <class OtherValue>
        config_iterator(config_iterator<OtherValue> const& other);

        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
        template <class> friend class config_iterator;

        template <class OtherValue>
        bool equal(config_iterator<OtherValue> const& other) const { } // Verify is two iterators are equals (used to verify if it == end)

        void increment() {} // Logic for incrementing the iterator
        Value& dereference() const {} // Returning the actual value

        // members
    };
}

typedef impl::iterator<type> iterator;
```

This is a template file for very simple iterator (forward), read the [Iterator Help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) for more info, the same can be implementing overloading the right operators (++ post a pre increment, *, ->, etc...), by boost provide a ways of defining the minimum necessary to implement the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What I ended up using was `boost::iterator_adaptor`, which itself is derived from `boost::iterator_facade`, but relies more on the provided base iterator class, i.e. in my case `Map::iterator`. The only function to implement was `void increment()` to handle the transition from different levels.

Comment: Well, and obviously a constructor taking a reference to the levels as explained by netvipec.